# Allure generation history (command line) limits

Tags: allure

We use Allure to generate reports from test runs. We have a requirement that reports will contain possibly over hundreds of runs (of same test suites). Currently we are only able to see 20 runs in the trend, and I noticed the PR "increase history limit to 20 (via #1059)" which has a hard coded 20 instead of 5. Is there a way to overwrite this limits?

Thanks.
m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised a [PR](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/pull/1331) with a quick fix for that. Already talked to Allure devs. There's a concern about the best place for the newly added piece of code. They will think about it.

In the meantime, you can build `allure` binary from the linked branch and just set an `ALLURE_RESULTS_LIMIT` env variable before calling `allure generate` command.

Note that it affects not only a history trend but all the other trends as well. You should also realize that new results will appear one by one starting from the most recent number, e.g. if you set `ALLURE_RESULTS_LIMIT=100` and the most recent report has only 20 results, the next run will give you 21, not 100 in a moment. It's an incremental process.